# Using jQuery I need to target a group of radio buttons and highlight the active one

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I have a group of radio buttons. Here is the first one:

```
<form action="../opt/logo/logo-options.php" method="post">
<table class="container" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td class="right"> 
            <div id="osta-toggle">
                  <input id="radio4" class="switch" type="radio" name="logo-options" value="default" <?php echo chk( $opt, "logo-options", "default" )?>>
                <label for="radio4">&nbsp;</label>  
            </div>  
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
etc.
```

I am using jQuery and CSS to highlight the active radio button.

```
    $('input:radio').click(function() {
        $("input:radio").each(function() {
            $(this).closest("table").toggleClass("highlight", $(this).is(":checked"));
        });
    });
```

When a button is toggled 'ON', the class `highlight` is added to the container.

```
<table class="container highlight" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
```

The problem is that I have another group of radio buttons on the same page.

My code works perfectly when it is isolated. But when it resides on the same page with other radio buttons it produces seemingly random results.

How can I tweak the jQuery to target my specific group of radio buttons?

Comment: Rather than doing this with javascript, why not make a CSS rule for the radios based on if they are `:checked` ?

Comment: That isn't a bad idea, @Taplar. But I want to target/style a previous div bases on the state of the radio button, which I don't believe is possible in CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably several ways to solve this, but one way would be to apply a specific class to the radio buttons you want to share this code.

```
<input id="radio4" class="switch highlight-control" type="radio" name="logo-options" value="default" <?php echo chk( $opt, "logo-options", "default" )?>>
```

Then in your jquery selector, only look at items with that class.
So `$('input:radio').click(function() {`
becomes `$('.highlight-control').click(function() {`

And do the same for the .each selector.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working on my end. To make sure we're on the same page, here is the jquery I'm using:

$('.highlight-control').click(function() {
    $(".highlight-control").each(function() {
        $(this).closest("table").toggleClass("highlight", $(this).is(":checked"));
    });
});

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by css, but if you want to continue using your event/function you can do something like that: Set all inputs to 'off' and only 'on' the clicked one:

```
$('input:radio').click(function() {
    $("input:radio").closest("table").removeClass('highlight');
    $(this).closest("table").addClass("highlight", $(this).is(":checked"));
});
```

Comment: Again, this works perfectly in codepen, or even isolated on its own page in my project. But as soon as it exists on the same page with other radio buttons it stops working. Hmmm, maybe something else is breaking it? I will investigate.

Comment: try using a preventDefault() and stopPropagation() on the event:
$('input:radio').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $("input:radio").closest("table").removeClass('highlight');
    $(this).closest("table").addClass("highlight", $(this).is(":checked"));
});

Answer (score 0):

If the table you're trying to style always encompasses the radio button, maybe try this:

```
    $('input:radio').click(function() {
        var tableContainer = $(this).parents('table');
        tableContainer.toggleClass('highlighted', $(this).is(':checked'));
    });
```